# How to recognize fieldnames in header row of text/csv file when importing in postgreSQL table ?

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, field-names

I want to import a fair number of `csv` files in a single `postgreSQL` table. The `csv` files differ in the number of fields they contain, but the header row contains `fieldnames` which correspond with those in the destination table.

Rather than specifying the fields present in each `csv` file using:

```
COPY destination_table (comma_separated_fields_in_source_file) FROM '/filepath'...
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to have `postgres / pgAdmin` recognise the fieldnames in the header row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is naughty, and untested, but might work:

```
bash -c 'echo copy tablename \(; head -1 filename; echo \) from stdin with format csv header\;; cat filename ' | psql
```

Answer (score 0):

COPY does not support this natively, you might, however, think of writing a function/stored procedure to handle this. Maybe using a 'Foreign Data Wrapper' to read the first line and dynamically create a 'COPY' SQL statement from this. See here for the text/csv Foreign Data Wrapper: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html